# Como puedo obtener el valor de la session laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de una session que creé así

```
Session::flash('ventaPendiente', $this->venta);
```

Y necesito verlo en otro controllador, pero me devuelve `null`.

Lo que hago es que envío un email y cuando abro la url del email supongo que debería mostrarme ¿la session o esta caduca?

La intento obtener así

```
$ventaPendiente = Session::get('ventaPendiente');
dd($ventaPendiente);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos cosas en tu código, una, le estás asignando el nombre `ventaPendiente` a tu variable de sesión y después la tratas de recuperar con un nombre diferente "`cocheAPagar`", lo correcto sería:

```
$ventaPendiente = session('ventaPendiente');
```

En segunda, puede que se pierda tu variable ya que las variables **flash** de **session** solo permanecen por **una** petición HTTP más, si quieres que dure durante toda la sesión del usuario deberías de guardarla de la siguiente forma:

```
session(['ventaPendiente' => $this->venta]);
```

Para recuperarla solo basta con usar:

```
session('ventaPendiente');
```

Si no existe te devolverá `null`

Comment: Tienes razón, pero es que tengo dos iguales, pero no va ni una ya las he probado y nada.

Comment: Con esta segunda opción me ha funcionado, muchas gracias.

Comment: @OscarPortillo Si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como la correcta. Recomiendo que uses la sintaxis que yo te proporcioné, ya que la que estás usando es como se hacía anteriormente, puede que en futuras versiones de Laravel se deje de usar.

Comment: si si, la estoy usando como me lo ha dicho usted. Muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: Este session pertenece ala librería Focade\Session???